# Highlight list words in a MS Word file

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

First I want to say that I don't know anything about VBA and I want to **highlight list words** which is in A.txt(or .doc) file **to a MS-Word file B.docx** that full of texts. I found a VBA code that works perfectly fine but It needs you put words into the code ***StrFnd = "dog,cat,pig,horse,man"***. Can you help me change it somehow the code gets list words file A.txt instead of typing these words. Thank you very much.

```js
Sub HiLightList()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim StrFnd As String, Rng As Range, i As Long
StrFnd = "dog,cat,pig,horse,man"
For i = 0 To UBound(Split(StrFnd, ","))
  Set Rng = ActiveDocument.Range
  With Rng.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Text = Split(StrFnd, ",")(i)
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.Highlight = True
    .Replacement.Text = "^&"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = True
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = True
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  End With
Next
Set Rng = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you highlighting words in file A with a certain color, and putting those words in file B ?

Comment: I use this code by "Alt + F11" > Insert Module> Paste Code and F5 to Run. The result I got is If in B file has these word "dog, cat,..vv" it will be highlighted. The problem is I have a long list word need to be highlighted in B file. So Do you know how to run the code without typing A list. Because my list words is very long and I had tried to copypatse all of it into the code but It didn't work.

Comment: Well you're not being very clear on what you want. First it appears as though you want a list of highlighted words out of one document and highlight those words in another document. Now you're saying you just have a list of words in one document that you want highlighted in another document.

Comment: I'm sorry about my english. Let me make it clear one more time. I have A file.txt that includes "cat,dog,car...vv" and also have a B file.docx (I love cat and dog). I open the B file and run the code what I get is Cat and Dog will be highlighted. And now I want you help me how to do that with the code I posted. The code worked without Afile but what I want is the code works with Afile. Because my Afile list is very long. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Look at the current answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this will look at the first document for the list of words, then highlight the same words in the current document.

```
Sub CompareWordList()
  Dim sCheckDoc As String
  Dim docRef As Document
  Dim docCurrent As Document
  Dim wrdRef As Object

sCheckDoc = "C:\highlight\A.txt"
Set docCurrent = Selection.Document
Set docRef = Documents.Open(sCheckDoc)
docCurrent.Activate

With Selection.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.Font.Bold = True
    .Replacement.Text = "^&"
    .Forward = True
    .Format = True
    .MatchWholeWord = True
    .MatchCase = True
    .MatchWildcards = False
End With

For Each wrdRef In docRef.Words
    If Asc(Left(wrdRef, 1)) > 32 Then
        With Selection.Find
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Text = wrdRef
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        End With
    End If
Next wrdRef

docRef.Close
docCurrent.Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: Your codes are too hard for me, after running I still don't understand how it can highlight words I want, I'm not a programmer. I just want to get data from C:\highlight\A.txt to replace this line StrFnd = "dog,cat,pig,horse,man". Because the list words too long that I can't put it in the code. The code I posted is working fine ( it's not my code).

Comment: Replaced the code. This is similar to what you have, so it should be easy to understand

Comment: It works, Thank you so much for spending your time to help me. OMG. I had spent a day search on google but can't find the solution for it. And now You come to help me out. Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help. Please choose my answer as the solution.

Comment: Yes. Thank you. Wish you all the best.