# VBA MS Word formating specific strings - code delets them instead

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to find some strings in a document and format them all in a specific way. I am confused because it worked and then just stopped working and instead of formating started deleting the text. I swear I didn't change anything :D :D :D. I am at least not aware of if.... :)

Can anyone see any issue in my code?

EDIT: Ok, so it works the first time I run it, and when I undo the changes in the document and run the code again, it deletes the lines... and it does not seem to be in this code, but somewhere in my other code. Is there some kind or "reset" of settings I need to include here, to avoid old run code to interfere?

```
Sub SimpleReplace()
    
    Dim markStrings(19) As String
    markStrings(0) = "some text"
    '....
    markStrings(19) = "some other"
     
     
    'mark the specific string to highlight them
    Call HighlightWords(markStrings)

End Sub
```

This is my function

```
'highlight all the different texts in an array
Function HighlightWords(ByRef highlightStrings() As String)

    Dim Words As Variant
    
    
    For Each Words In highlightStrings
    
        'Clear existing formatting and settings in Find feature.
        Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
        Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
        
        'set formating
        With Selection.Find.Replacement.Font
            .Bold = True
            .TextColor.RGB = RGB(240, 130, 50)
            .Italic = True
        End With
        
        'Cycle through document and find words in collection.
        'Highlight words when found.
        
         With Selection.Find
            .Text = Words
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
        End With
        Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    Next

End Function
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try adding `Selection.Find.Replacement.Text = Words`

Comment: Or try the code here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46142800/highlight-list-words-in-a-ms-word-file

Comment: Selection.Find.Replacement.Text = Words works. But with that, I always replace the text with itself, right. Isn't that just more of a workaround?

Comment: Yes it probably is.  You can try instead fully resetting the Find eg using `ResetFindParameters` from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60750388/need-to-expand-multiple-find-and-replace-in-ms-word-from-a-list-in-ms-excel-to-r/60806948#60806948

Comment: What is your Selection? I think it changes between first and next iteration. It would be better to use range (e.g., ActiveDocument.Range).

Answer (score 0):

If you execute Find using a range object instead of the selection object, you don't need to worry about resetting the Find/Replace properties which would otherwise persist and potentially cause problems with other code. Plus it's much faster. You could try using the following version of your function instead and see if that helps.

```
Function HighlightWords(ByRef highlightStrings() As String)
    Dim Words As Variant
    Dim rng As Range
    
    For Each Words In highlightStrings
        Set rng = ActiveDocument.Content
        
        With rng.Find
            With .Replacement.Font
                .Bold = True
                .Color = RGB(240, 130, 50)
                .Italic = True
            End With
            .Execute Words, Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        End With
    Next
End Function
```